# APNS, how do I fix "unable to get local issuer certificate" error on raspberry Pi when program works on Mac?

Tags: python, ios, raspberry-pi, apple-push-notifications, http2

I'm trying to send an iOS push notification through a python script that works on my Mac but the program gets the error "httpcore.ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)" when I run it on my Raspberry Pi. I've tried adding the GeoTrust and the new AAACertificateServices certs, but maybe I did something wrong there. Certs perpetually confuse me so I would really appreciate the help. I'm using Token-based authentication so I'm a bit confused as to what certs the errors are referring to in the first place...

Running on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with Debian.

The whole Traceback is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_exceptions.py", line 326, in map_exceptions
    yield
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 861, in _send_single_request
    (status_code, headers, stream, ext) = transport.request(
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 218, in request
    response = connection.request(
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 93, in request
    self.socket = self._open_socket(timeout)
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 119, in _open_socket
    return self.backend.open_tcp_stream(
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/sync.py", line 143, in open_tcp_stream
    return SyncSocketStream(sock=sock)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.0/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 12, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc) from None
httpcore.ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jake/Programming/Security/MQTT/NotificationServer.py", line 73, in <module>
    sendAlarmNotification()
  File "/home/jake/Programming/Security/MQTT/NotificationServer.py", line 66, in sendAlarmNotification
    r = client.post('{}/3/device/{}'.format(server, deviceToken), json=notification, headers=headers)
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 992, in post
    return self.request(
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 733, in request
    return self.send(
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 767, in send
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 805, in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 837, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_single_request(request, timeout)
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 861, in _send_single_request
    (status_code, headers, stream, ext) = transport.request(
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.0/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/jake/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_exceptions.py", line 343, in map_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message, **kwargs) from exc  # type: ignore
httpx.ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)
```

My code is

```
import httpx
import time
from jwcrypto import jwt, jwk

devServer = "https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com:443"
prodServer = "https://api.push.apple.com:443"
server = devServer 

pemFilePath = "pushCerts/PushNotificationAuthKey_**********.p8"

# This generates an auth token with the current time, using our pem files
def generateAuthToken(): 
    issueTime = int(time.time())
    token = jwt.JWT( header={ "alg" : "ES256", "kid" : "**********"}, claims={ "iss": "********", "iat": issueTime} )
    with open(pemFilePath, "rb") as pemfile:
        key = jwk.JWK.from_pem(pemfile.read())
    token.make_signed_token(key)
    return token.serialize()
 

deviceToken = "long device token" 
authToken = 'bearer ' + generateAuthToken()
pushType = 'alert'                                      
expiration = '3600'                                         
priority = '10'                                                     
topic = 'com.MyName.MyAppName'  

headers = { 
    'authorization' : authToken,
    'apns-push-type' : pushType,
    'apns-expiration' : expiration,
    'apns-priority' : priority,
    'apns-topic' : topic
    }

def sendAlarmNotification():
    notification = { "aps" : { "alert": "Alarm Triggered!", "sound" : { "critical": 1, "name": "Alarm.caf", "volume": 1.0 }}}
    client = httpx.Client(http2=True)
    try:
        r = client.post('{}/3/device/{}'.format(server, deviceToken), json=notification, headers=headers)
        print(r)
    finally:
        client.close()

sendAlarmNotification()
```

Also, running `openssl s_client -connect api.sandbox.push.apple.com:443` came back as successfully verified so I'm real confused.

Answer (score 0):

From here: https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/
it looks like you need to specify the pem file in the httpx call:

import httpx

r = httpx.get("https://example.org", verify="path/to/client.pem")

Comment: So why would I need to do that on the Pi and not on my Mac, since the program runs perfectly on my Mac? And I would be supplying the GeoTrust pem file since I'm authenticating via token?

Comment: Tried it with the GeoTrust cert to no avail :/

Comment: You're going to an apple.com address and the MAC likely has that certificate chain on it by default so it can communicate with Apple, the Pi wouldn't by default.

The reason you get this when using token based authentication is that the connection is SSL and that needs to be verified first. 

Not sure why GeoTrust is there, you need to validate the cert used by https://api.push.apple.com/   which looks to be issued by Apple. 

You can try verify=False and if that works, then you don't have the correct certificate change to verify the ssl used by https://api.push.apple.com/

Comment: GeoTrust is Apple's APNS cert you need, their website stating "Creating that connection requires installing the GeoTrust Global CA root certificate...on each of your provider servers." If I'm understanding correctly? I don't know what other cert I would use... I tried verify=False and that did not change anything. Any more insight?